# Custom color of the button on over on WPF

Tags: wpf, button, colors

How can I change the color of the button when you are over it with the mouse from the default blue to another color?

Comment: In the linked question, just change the `Button.IsFocused` property in the `Trigger` to `Button.IsMouseOver` to have mouse over effects... you should be able to work it out.

Comment: I made it in a little different way but I used this principle, thanks